# RJAGS syntax error using Truncation of normal prior in random effects model

Tags: normal-distribution, truncation

I am running a random effects model in rjags with code:

```
    model{ 
for (i in 1:N) {
mu1[i]<-(da1[1]+pow(10,(pka1[2]-ph[i]))*da1[2]+pow(10,(pka1[1]+pka1[2]-2*ph[i]))*da1[3])/(1+pow(10,(pka1[2]-ph[i]))+pow(10,(pka1[1]+pka1[2]-2*ph[i])))

mu2[i]<-(da2[1]+pow(10,(pka2[2]-ph[i]))*da2[2]+pow(10,(pka2[1]+pka2[2]-2*ph[i]))*da2[3])/(1+pow(10,(pka2[2]-ph[i]))+pow(10,(pka2[1]+pka2[2]-2*ph[i])))

}

MU[1:N,1]<-mu1
MU[1:N,2]<-mu2

for (i in 1:N) {
Y[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(MU[i,1:2],SIGMA)
}

SIGMA ~ dwish(R,5)

for (i in 1:2) {
pka[i] ~ dunif(0,14)
}

pka<-sort(pka)

for (i in 1:2) {
pka1[i]<-dnorm(pka[i],1)T(0,14)
pka2[i]<-dnorm(pka[i],1)T(0,14)
}

for (i in 1:3) {
da1[i] ~ dunif(0,10)
da2[i] ~ dunif(0,10)
}

}
```

and get the error:

```
Error in jags.model("model2b.txt", data = data, n.chains = 4, n.adapt = 10) : 
Error parsing model file:syntax error on line 25 near "T"
```

I have run for a less complex version of mu which has only a single pka1 and pka2 and the model runs perfectly. Any help in spotting the syntax error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in 1:2) {
pka1[i]<-dnorm(pka[i],1)T(0,14)
pka2[i]<-dnorm(pka[i],1)T(0,14)
}
```

The `<-` should be `~`

This is one of the problems, maybe there are others.